# Literature for invariant metric on Lie-groups

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, invariance

For my thesis I am working with biinvariant metrics.

I found this chapter [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvzrq1q53sAhWFqqQKHYI-DzwQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cis.upenn.edu%2F~cis610%2Fcis610-15-sl17.pdf&usg=AOvVaw03lDSPZvGaKH8HjimGoWiB](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjvzrq1q53sAhWFqqQKHYI-DzwQFjABegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cis.upenn.edu%2F%7Ecis610%2Fcis610-15-sl17.pdf&usg=AOvVaw03lDSPZvGaKH8HjimGoWiB)
during my Google research and want to cite something.

Does anyone recognize the book where this chapter is from. Unfortunately it does not contain any hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a preliminary version of chapter 21 of the recently released book

[Differential Geometry and Lie Groups - A Computational Perspective](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030460396)

by Jean Gallier and Jocelyn Quaintance.